# JSS layout service not working with Sitecore Commerce 9.1

Tags: sitecore-commerce, jss

I have `SXM 9.1` and `Sitecore XC 9.1` installed. Our requirement is to create `SXC` website headless. So I installed `Sitecore JSS (Sitecore JavaScript Services 11.1.0)` but while installing it asked to overwrite the  layout service. I allowed replacing all.

After installation, when I access to check the layout service, it is not working.

Is there any compatibility issue with `Sitecore XC 9.1` and `Sitecore JSS 11.1`?

Comment: "when I access to check the layout service, it is not working" - what does it mean it is not working? What kind of exception you have there? How you are accessing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to NOT overwrite all, when asked. SXA has some things sitting in LayoutService which has now been overwritten by JSS.

You need to restore your backup to the point before you installed JSS, then re-install it and select "Merge" when asked, instead.

For the record, Sitecore does not officially support JSS 11 and SXA 1.8.1.  You need Sitecore 9.2 and JSS 12 for official support.